# Appending to closest div of a class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-autocomplete

I have a web application that uses the jQuery autocomplete function. On my webpage I have several text boxes with the autocomplete class attached to them and beneath them empty divs for the autocomplete results to append to. Currently, no matter which text box I type in, it appends to the div under the first text box. How would I get it to append to the one below the box I'm typing in?

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input.autocomplete").autocomplete({
    appendTo: '.container',
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetUsers',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { query: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item, value: item };
                }));
            }
        })  ;
    }
});
})
</script>
```

HTML (there are 18 textboxes total, but I felt this would be enough to show what I was doing):

```
Employee Name (Team Leader): <input type ="text" name="empName1" class="autocomplete"/>
    <div class ="container"></div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Employee Name (Event Process Owner): <input type ="text" name="empName2" class="autocomplete"/>
    <div class ="container"></div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Employee Name (Sponsor): <input type ="text" name="sponsor" class="autocomplete"/>
    <div class ="container"></div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Employee Name: <input type ="text" name="empName3" class="autocomplete"/>
    <div class ="container"></div>
    Employee Name: <input type ="text" name="empName4" class="autocomplete"/>
    <div class ="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the `appendTo` option. Try the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input.autocomplete").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            name = $this.attr('name');
        $this.autocomplete({
            appendTo: 'input[name=' + name + '] + .container',
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/GetUsers',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { query: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item, value: item };
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**Working Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/muwxt/

```
$('input').each(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        search: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).next('.container').empty();
        },
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                 url: '/Home/GetUsers',
                 type: "POST",
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: { query: request.term },
                 success: function (data) {
                       response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item, value: item };
                         })
                       );
                 }  
            });
        }
    }).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

        return $('<li/>')
            .data('item.autocomplete', item)
            .append(item.value)
            .appendTo($(this.element).next('.container'));
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. When I try that I get an error in jquery-ui-1.8.20 that reads "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'element': object is null or undefined"

Comment: @TheZuck No, when I try that one it's still the same error in the comment above

Comment: When I use that code, nothing happens. I don't even see any network activity from the AJAX call

Comment: Forget that last comment, I forgot to put $(document).ready It does appear under the correct box, but now the formatting of the results has disappeared and the results stay under the textbox and I can't select any items from the results without getting the error "Unable to get value of the property 'top': object is null or undefined"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can change the HTML but this would work:

HTML (for the first autocomplete box)

```
Employee Name (Team Leader): <input type ="text" name="empName1" class="autocomplete"/>
<div class ="empName1 container"></div>
```

JS

```
$("input.autocomplete").autocomplete({
    appendTo: '.container.' + $(this).attr('name'),
```

You should also add this to your ajax call:

```
error: function() { response(""); }
```

Because, as it is said in the autocomplete API documentation

> You must always call the response callback even if you encounter an
>   error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

Comment: When I try that I get the error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'attr'"

Comment: No worries. When I add that change I get "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'element': object is null or undefined" when I start to type in the text box

Comment: Edited again, maybe that would fix it

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I still get the same error. Even with those changes

Answer (score 0):

I think my solution will slow the loading, but work (i hope).

First add all you `.container` an id but dont remove the class.

then use each :

```
$('.autocomplet').each(function(){
    var target = $(this)
    target.autocomplete({
        appendTo: getcontainer(target),
        source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetUsers',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { query: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item, value: item };
                }));
            }
        })  ;
    }
})
```

To not lose the reference of the target, we save it in a var.
Append only accept selector, so we make a function that will return a selector:

```
function getContainer(target){
    var selectedID = target.next('.container').attr('id');
    return '#'+selectedID;
}
```

Comment: When I try that I get the errot "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'target' is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

In the success function of the ajax call you could use jquery templates (google jquery.tmpl) to append html to some div's, taking into account the sender to decide which div to go to.. I had this problem myself and this solution worked alright.

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete results appended in correct divs. Just wrapped a textfield and a div together.  : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r6cm4/1/)**

**JQuery:** Modified the jquery portion a little bit, as below **-**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",      "AppleScript",      "Asp",      "BASIC",      "C",      "C++",
  "Clojure",      "COBOL",      "ColdFusion",      "Erlang",      "Fortran",      "Groovy",
  "Haskell",      "Java",      "JavaScript",      "Lisp",      "Perl",      "PHP",
  "Python",      "Ruby",      "Scala",      "Scheme"
];

try{

    $(".autocomplete").each(function(){
        $(this).autocomplete({
search: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).parent().find('.container').empty();
    },
source: availableTags,
}).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(div, item) {

return $('<li/>')
   .data('item.autocomplete', item)
   .append(item.value)
.appendTo($(':focus').parent().find('.container'));
};
})
}
catch(e){alert(e)}  })
```